# Mail not sending in Ruby on Rails (formerly redirect quirk in production for Depot)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 app that works perfectly in development mode on my local machine running Ruby 2.0.

I recently deployed to Heroku (which I know little about) but that I believe to be the same environment - though I am not sure how to check.

In any case - It runs *almost* flawlessly on Heroku as well except for one failed redirect.
(this is the depot application described in Agile Web Development with Rails 4)

After a user places an order at example.com/orders/new? - they are taken to the rails "something went wrong" page at example.com/orders rather than being redirected to the store home url

The order still gets saved and is viewable from the admin panel - but the user never gets taken home like they do on my local machine. Any ideas?

**Order Controller**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:new, :create]

  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    if @cart.line_items.empty?
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"
      return
    end

    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice:
          'Thank you for your order.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :notes, :email, :location)
    end
end
```

**Edit 2**
(Adding mailer configuration for production fixed my issue - but mail is still not being delivered)
**production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method       = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings         = {
    address:        "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:           587,
    domain:         "gmail.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    user_name:      "my_email_address@gmail.com",
    password:       "my_password",
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your full trace.

Comment: have you setup mailer in your `config/environments/production.rb`?

Comment: Have you checked the Heroku log?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Just added the log in Edit 1

Comment: @j03w You caught it - that fixed my issue. Mail isn't delivering though. (I used to think it was just because I was testing on my local machine - this seems to be the case in production too though)

Comment: May be change `domain` to your app. Something like `your-app-name.herokuapp.com`  if you don't have your own domain yet.

Comment: You might also include...  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
in your production.rb. Also, while using gmail is perfectly fine, I really like SendGrid with Heroku. It's got a free tier and a snap to setup. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#ruby-rails